# Adding marker to map in DialogFragment: Cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have this fragment class for my Map Dialog:

```
public static class MapDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        public static MapDialogFragment newInstance(float latitude, float longitude) {
            MapDialogFragment frag = new MapDialogFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putFloat("latitude", latitude);
            args.putFloat("longitude", longitude);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
        }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        float latitude = getArguments().getFloat("latitude");
        float longitude = getArguments().getFloat("longitude");

        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_dialog, null);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setView(view)
        .setTitle("Store Map")
        .setNegativeButton("Done",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                })
                .create();
        }
    }
```

This pulls up the map in the dialog fragment, here's the custom inflated view:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

When I try to add a marker to the map (following the [Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker)), I add this line:

```
storeMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

I get this error: `Cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment`

At the top of my activity, I do have: `private GoogleMap storeMap;`

How do I add a marker in a `DialogFragment` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not mixing support library fragments (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment` with native fragments (`android.app.Fragment`) - they all need to be in sync. If you are using support library fragments, you should use [SupportMapFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html) in place of MapFragment.